# What is the best way to update SQL Server CE table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, crud

I have 2 tables.
Table **Movie**
- id (PK)
- title
- type

Table **Episode**
- id (PK)
- episode (PK)
- title

Each Movie has some Episodes.

**Movie**

```
---------------------------------
| id | title       | type       |
|----|-------------|------------|
| 1  | movie1      | 3 episodes |
| 2  | movie2      | 2 episodes |
---------------------------------
```

**Episode**

```
----------------------------------------
| id | episode     | title             |
|----|-------------|-------------------|
| 1  | 1           | movie1 episode 1  |
| 1  | 2           | movie1 episode 2  |
| 1  | 3           | movie1 episode 3  |
| 2  | 1           | movie2 episode 1  |
| 2  | 2           | movie2 episode 2  |
----------------------------------------
```

If I update record id="1" (on both table), I often use:
Table **Movie**:

```
Update Movie set title='...', type='...' where id=1;
```

Table **Episode**

```
Delete from Episode where id=1;
Insert into Episode(id, episode, title) values('...', '...', '...');
```

I think it's a stupid way to update Table Episode. I just can't think another way to update the record consider user may change, add, or delete some record on table and then save all change to database.

Anyone have another solution?

**EDIT:**

ex. 
User do some change on Table Episode (just id=1)
**Episode**

```
----------------------------------------
| id | episode     | title             |
|----|-------------|-------------------|
| 1  | 1           | movie1 episode 1  |
| 1  | 2           | movie1 episode 1a |
| 1  | 3           | movie1 episode 2  |
| 1  | 4           | movie1 episode 3a |
| 1  | 5           | movie1 episode 3b |
----------------------------------------
```

How can I store all that change to database?

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal I want to store all value (after add, edit, or delete by user) to database.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can solve your problem:

```
update Movie m inner join Episode e on m.id = e.id and m.id = 1 set m.title = 'your_value', e.title = 'your value'
```

DB: MYSQL 5.5

Comment: It's only update the current value on the table. But, if user add, delete and edit records on table I can't use that query? ex. current Table Episode (id=1) has 3 rows, then user add new row, delete some row, and edit certain row. How can I store all that value (after all changed by user) to database?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your table structure a bit, then you don't need all the updates.

i.e. Movie.Type could be calculated by doing a SELECT COUNT(*) on Episode (by Movie ID). I don't see why you need to store Movie.Type, and Episode.Title could also be calculated, you would only need to store the Episode Title in the Episode table instead of Movie Title + Episode Title. That way you could just calculate the titles in your query instead of storing redundant data and then worrying about how to update it.

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain it correctly on OP. But Movie.Title value is not the same with Episode.Title. And Movie.Type value is not always show how many episode the movie has. I just put it like the OP in order to simplify the example.